# addClass If Any of a Set of Conditions Are Present

Tags: jquery

I have a series of conditions that if any of them are true (present in the DOM) then I want to addClass to the body. I want to know if there is a simpler or more concise way than what I have ...

```
if ($('.blog-entry').length > 0) {
    $("body").addClass('stock-plugin');
}
if ($('.contact-form').length > 0) {
    $("body").addClass('stock-plugin');
}

if ($('.fileshare').length > 0) {
    $("body").addClass('stock-plugin');
}
```

Technically, it works to do it that way, however, I thought that I could do something like this to achieve the same thing, except that it only works on the first condition:

```
if($('.blog-entry' || '.contact-form' || '.fileshare').length >0 ){
    $("body").addClass('stock-plugin');   
}
```

What am I doing wrong, or am I trying to hard?

Comment: You are applying the `||` operator to the strings, and the result of `'.blog-entry' || '.contact-form'` is `'.blog-entry'`. A non-empty string acts as a *truthy* value for the `||` operator, what you did comes down to "take 1st string, unless it is empty, then take 2nd string, etc"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This last selector will not work, obviously. This is basically going to pick the first truthy value, in this case `'.blog-entry'`.

But you can use jQuery selector for multiple classes, like this:

```
if($('.blog-entry, .contact-form, .fileshare').length > 0 ){
    $("body").addClass('stock-plugin');   
}
```

You can also use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/), that will add a new set of elements to the previous selector, like this:

```
if($('.blog-entry').add('.contact-form').add('.fileshare').length > 0 ){
    $("body").addClass('stock-plugin');   
}
```

Comment: Hey ... that was a big help! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery allows you to define more than one selector to look for by separating them with commas:

```
if($('.blog-entry, .contact-form, .fileshare').length > 0 ){
    $("body").addClass('stock-plugin');   
}
```